# Python, any alternative to memory dict consuming less memory for key=>value access

Tags: python, dictionary, memory-efficient

Using Python 2.7.x family, I have the following trouble, I need to have a dict structure to have very quick access on the basis of a `D[key] = value` so dict are supposed to be perfect.

BTW, I had `MemoryError` because I need to have in memory two families of objects which both of them are huge (many hundred million) and linked: this dict and also a structure of linked tree objects too (actually tries).

Is there any alternative to dict python objects that have very low memory footprint?

The value will be an "id" (string) and the key will be a * Unicode * string (so with the accentuated and other strange characters, it seems I cannot use the `intern` construct as Unicode).

Are there any tools that can help me even with some little loosing of performance for the hashing process (not too much ;)). What can be common good practice for such design? (I would like to avoid the solution relying on an external database, as the process is already quite slow, and I need too much of these objects access.)

Comment: do you mean `low memory footprint` instead of `low fingerprint memory`?

Comment: python > 3.6 dictionaries

Comment: You say opposite things: you need fast accesses so do not way external databases, and at the same time you have not enough memory. I can see only 2 ways: use faster disks or buy additional memory...

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Didn't they get better in 3.6 already?

Comment: Yes, my bad; I meant starting 3.6

Comment: sorry for my english, yes it was low memory footprint

Answer (score 0):

The module [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shelve.html) offers a persistent dictionary that should server your needs:

```
>>> import shelve
>>> db = shelve('cache.db')
>>> db = shelve.open('cache.db')
>>> db['id1'] = u'string data'
>>> db['id1']
'string data'
```

You can use it just like an ordinary dictionary, but it stores all data in a key-value store in a file (database). This might be fast enough for your needs because there is some caching going on in the background. The effort to try it out should be rather small.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

- Switch to Python 3.6.

Dictionaries got a LOT better in 3.6.  Faster, smaller footprint, ordered by default, and I'm sure I'm forgetting something.

- Get more memory.

You're clearly doing something bounded by memory on a machine that doesn't fit the bill.  Buy more RAM, or rent an m4.xlarge AWS instance, or something.

- Redefine the problem.

Do you *need* all million items in memory at once?  Are you working on them all at once?  Almost definitely not.  Write your algorithms smarter, to work on the data chunks at a time, or even items at a time.  If you make this concurrent ([not necessarily parallel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cN_DpYBzKso)), most of the wait time will be IO, and can easily be threaded in Python.

Try making use of generator expressions and generators in general.  Their memory usage is tiny.

- Use a database

Databases are specifically around to solve this problem.  Write a small importer to chuck your data into MySQL or MongoDB, then express your problem in SQL.

Comment: Not convinced about the Python 3.6 option. I tried `sys.getsizeof({str(i): str(i) for i in range(10**6)})`. Python 2.7.14 said 25165964, Python 3.6.4 said 25165888. Almost the same, just 76 difference.

Comment: That's because you're using sequential keys.  Take a look at [Raymond Hettinger's excellent talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p33CVV29OG8).

Comment: I watched that recently already. His space-efficiency advertisement was for dictionaries of size **5**, which are so small that 76 bytes indeed are significant. But with the OP's "many hundred million" items that's nothing. Also, what do you mean with "sequential keys"?

Comment: Your keys are in sequence.  `0`, `1`, `2`...  Observe.  Python 2: `getsizeof({randint(0,100000): str(uuid4()) for i in xrange(10000)})` = 786,712.  Python 3: `getsizeof({randint(0, 100000): str(uuid4()) for i in range(10000)})` = 393,312.

Comment: No, my keys are `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`... And yours would better be strings as well, as that's what the OP has. Also, size 10000 still isn't comparable to "many hundred million".

Comment: The sizes are the exact same in both cases with strings for keys instead of ints.  Do you disagree that four hundred thousand is less than eight hundred thousand?  Try it for yourself.

Comment: I do get a similarly large difference for that irrelevantly small case, yes. Not for large ones. But I figured out the real reason (not "sequential keys"), maybe I'll make that a new question+answer.

Comment: I need to compare an unknown item to do  similarity checking against all the one known. But, yes most of the advices provided as an answer are clearly clever and good ideas. Btw i was trying first to do what needed with  current hardware, and i am already facing some MemoryError while handling only 20 millions of them... I was surprised that such dict was consuming so much and was expecting some tips. BTW, using a database make computation times to explode (string compare) and so way to slow for any http stuffs. So i am still looking for some other way... Also no swith to 3.6 for now possible

Comment: Look into bloom filters.